# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynatpmp'

Tags: python-3.x, importerror

I'm getting a ModuleNotFoundError while trying to import py-natpmp module described at pypi.org.
I'm using Python3.10.6 as the interpreter in VScode and the system with Ubuntu 22.4.2LTS, but I'm pretty sure that's nothing to do with the version as the documentation doesn't show any example on how to import it so it's easy to get misspelled.

I tried to retype the name with '-', but it didn't work and I also tried without the '-' and without spaces and still no result. I'm expecting to import this module.